# python 2.7 error: 'raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError' when using urlopen in class

Tags: python-2.7

I have created the following function, which works fine:

```
def executeMethod(inJson):
  global FunctionCalls
  global Logger
  FunctionCalls.append("executeMethod")
  print(inJson)
  print("")
  url = API_URL
  headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
  data = json.dumps(inJson)
  print (data)
  print("")
  req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  print (json.loads(response))
  try:
      return json.loads(response)["serviceId"]
  except:
      return -1
```

Now that I know it works, I am trying to incorporate this code into a class:

```
    def executeMethod(self):
       self.FunctionCalls.append("executeMethod")
       print(self.jsonBody)
       print("")
       url = self.API_URL
       headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
       data = json.dumps(self.jsonBody)
       print (data)
       print("")
       req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
       response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
       print (json.loads(response))
       try:
           return json.loads(response)["serviceId"]
       except:
           return -1
```

But when I try to use this class function, I get the following error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError
```

With no HTTP error code or anything. I have compared the code multiple times, and even recreated the class function from the function where it was working. I'm don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Update, it appears the request body was the issue, not the code. Runs fine when I pass the JSON expected by the server.

Comment: then please delete your question, as it's useless to anyone else.